# Open picture via VBA ( Excel) from web without Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel

I use code to open pictures from web using Internet Explorer. Now I want to do it without Internet Explorer e.g. in paint or windows photo viewer. I sent my VBA code with using IE. Could you help me ? Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Path As String, s As String
    Path = "http://08.15.40.22:0603/tralala/get_doc.pl?doc_id="

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H7:H30")) Is Nothing _
    And Target.Count = 1 Then
        If IsNumeric(Target) And Len(Target) > 0 Then
            s = Left(Target, Len(Target) - 2)
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Path & s
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `Shell` command:

```
Shell "RunDLL32.exe C:\Windows\System32\Shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen " & Path & s
```

This opens Windows Picture & Fax Viewer full-screen with the image.

Or in MSPaint:

```
Shell Chr(34) & "C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Path & s & Chr(34), 1
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for help but now I have problem with printing.  Some buttons  are non active in Windows Picture & Fax Viewer. I can open only those buttons File and Open.  So I am not able  to print  the picture. 

Could you help me?

Comment: Please **stop** trying to edit my answer to include your comments and screenshots. Anyways, your original question says "I want to open pictures in MS Paint or Photo Viewer".  Does this not answer that problem?

Comment: If this has solved the original problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted. If you now have a *new* and different problem, I would encourage you to ask it as a new question. When I test this code, all the buttons are enabled, so I am not sure how much I could help with your follow-up, but it's very possible that someone else can help you with that :)

Comment: I am sorry for editing. My original problem was solved but appeared a new problem. I try solve it myself. Thank you.

Comment: I would encourage you to ask a *new* question, that way the entire forum will be able to see it and hopefully assist you. And do consider accepting this answer, to indicate that it has solved the problem.